# How to replace string: \\\" with an empty string

Tags: java

I want to remove `\\\"` from a string using java. I have tried with the code mentioned below but I could not get the expected result.

```
str.replaceAll("\\\"","");
```

input string:

```
{\"name\":\"keyword\",\"value\":\"\\\"duck''s\\\"\",\"compareVal\":\"contains\"}
```

expected string:

```
{\"name\":\"keyword\",\"value\":\"duck''s\",\"compareVal\":\"contains\"}
```

Comment: Why str.replaceAll and not str.replace?

Comment: You can use [Matcher.quoteReplacement(  String s )](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#quoteReplacement(java.lang.String)) so you don't have to escape "special" characters

Answer (score 2):

Use `replace()`:

```
str = str.replace("\\\\\"", "");
```

`replaceAl()` uses regex for its search term (which would require a more complex string literal), but you don't need regex - your search term is plain text.

Note also that java string literals require each of your search characters to be escaped (by a leading backslash).

Comment: In particular, Java uses \ as its escape character, so any \ itself needs to be escaped.  Other uses for escape characters:  `\"` (a literal quote character), `\n` (a line feed), `\r` (a character return), etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replace("\\\\\"","");
```

Explanation:

- First \ => escaping a '\'
- Second \ => escaping a '\'
- \" => escaping '"'

Because \ and " are reserved symbols you have to indicate you want to treat them as the symbol they are by escaping with \ before.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void main(String s[])
    {
        String inputString = "\\\"name\\\"";
        String outputString = inputString.replace("\\", "").replace("\"","");
        System.out.println("Output string is as following :" + outputString);
    }
```